# IntelliJ IDEA 14 IDETalk with hangouts

Tags: intellij-idea, google-talk, google-hangouts

Is it possible to set IEDTalk to use gtalk or hangouts? I don't know server and port. I've tried both  `gtalk.google.com:5223` and `gtalk.google.com:5222` but they didn't work.

IntelliJ IDEA version is 14. Ubuntu 14.04 is my OS.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried talk.google.com:443 ?

See below screenshot of configuration dialog. After you entered your googlemail/gmail account it should work.

To open this dialog go to View->Tool Windows->IDETalk, then press the button with tools icon in the IDETalk window, a dropdown appears with the menu item "edit jabber account" - press this one and the dialog screenshoted should show up.

[image]

Comment: So this works for me, with idea 14.0.3 and all version down to 12 as far as i remember.

Comment: I believe the only API that Hangouts provides is a javascript/browser integration.

Comment: ok my bad ... it does not work (jabber is not supported anymore by google) ... just seemed to work because all guy on work used their google accounts as username and we all sit in one network. sorry for that one.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but if anyone is interested IDETalk does work with google chat.

Server: talk.google.com : 223
User: xxxx@gmail.com
Password: ••••••

then check Remember Password.